# Issue with Android Emulator Directional pad Buttons looks

Tags: android-emulator

In the extended controls of android emulator, i have an issue with messed up graphics of Directional Pad buttons.

Does someone know what might be the issue here. Also, i was wondering if new buttons with different Key event functionalities could be added to the Directional Pad.

[image: image with the issue described above]

Comment: Can you try using API 31 or 29?

Comment: I have to use API 33 for this project. Any idea how this issue could be fixed? Can i soemhow change these buttons in the android image or emulator files?

Comment: Looks like the icon/mask is slightly shifted, possibly due to not enough space. Have you tried resizing the window, particularly enlarging it?

Comment: As Andrew stated it might be a solution. Also try disabling the Google Assistant text box beside it (if there is an option to, there should be)